# Constraints better as equation (hard) or objective (soft)?

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt, gekko

Is it generally easier for a gradient-based optimizer (APOPT, IPOPT) in Gekko to solve a constraint as an objective function (minimize to zero) or as an equation where it is set equal to zero? I set up the [Rosenbrock function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function) as an example. The optimal objective can either be set to zero as an equation (hard constraint) or minimized to zero (soft constraint).

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
a=1; b=100
print('Exact: ',a,a**2)

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Var(0); y=m.Var(0);
m.Minimize((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2)
m.options.SOLVER=1; m.solve(disp=False)
print('Soft: ',x.value[0],y.value[0],'Iterations:',m.options.ITERATIONS)

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Var(0); y=m.Var(0);
m.Equation((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2==0)
m.options.SOLVER=1; m.solve(disp=False)
print('Hard: ',x.value[0],y.value[0],'Iterations:',m.options.ITERATIONS)

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Var(0); y=m.Var(0);
m.Minimize((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2)
m.Equation((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2==0)
m.options.SOLVER=1; m.solve(disp=False)
print('Both: ',x.value[0],y.value[0],'Iterations:',m.options.ITERATIONS)
```

It may be too hard to generalize for all problems but I'm interested in the trade-offs, especially for large-scale problems where some of the constraints can be soft, hard, or both. For the Rosenbrock problem, the results are nearly identical but the soft constraint method has fewest iterations.

```
Exact:  1 1
Soft:  0.99999999441 0.99999999029 Iterations: 23
Hard:  0.99969681373 0.99942834333 Iterations: 26
Both:  0.99988305657 0.99978643823 Iterations: 27
```

Answer (score 0):

I use hard constraints when a feasible solution can be found and soft constraints when it is difficult to find a feasible solution or when violation of the constraints is acceptable but discouraged. Hard constraint equations are better for large-scale applications because the constraints are not all lumped together into one objective function value. The optimizer uses the gradient information from the equations to find a search direction for a feasible solution. For comparison, here is `scipy.optimize.minimize` with the same problems.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def f(z):
    x,y=z
    return (a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2
sol = minimize(f,[0,0])
print('Soft:',sol.x,'Iterations:',sol.nit)

def f(z):
    return 0
def con(z):
    x,y=z
    return (a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2
hard = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': con}
sol = minimize(f,[0,0],constraints=hard)
print('Hard:',sol.x,'Iterations:',sol.nit)

def f(z):
    x,y=z
    return (a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2
def con(z):
    x,y=z
    return (a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2
hard = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': con}
sol = minimize(f,[0,0],constraints=hard)
print('Both:',sol.x,'Iterations:',sol.nit)
```

The first form (soft constraint, objective function) has the fewest iterations.

```
Exact:  1 1
Soft: [0.99999467 0.99998932] Iterations: 19
Hard: [0.99986205 0.99963916] Iterations: 22
Both: [1.00013127 1.00021689] Iterations: 23
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about specific solvers in Gekko, you can run with `m.options.SOLVER=0` to try all available solvers and display a summary of the performance. With `SOLVER=0`, no solution is returned to Gekko so there is an error that can be caught with a `try` `except` block.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Rosenbrock function
a=1; b=100
print('Exact: ',a,a**2)

try:
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    x = m.Var(0); y=m.Var(0);
    m.Minimize((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2)
    m.options.SOLVER=0; m.solve(disp=True,debug=0)
except:
    pass

try:
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    x = m.Var(0); y=m.Var(0);
    m.Equation((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2==0)
    m.options.SOLVER=0; m.solve(disp=True,debug=0)
except:
    pass

try:
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    x = m.Var(0); y=m.Var(0);
    m.Minimize((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2)
    m.Equation((a-x)**2 + b*(y-x**2)**2==0)
    m.options.SOLVER=0; m.solve(disp=True,debug=0)
except:
    pass
```

All solvers (including BPOPT) are successful with the hard constraint approach. IPOPT iterations aren't reported automatically so I took it from the solver print-out.

```
 Solver      Variables Equations Res Evals Jac Evals Iter Info   Objective  Solution Time  Status
 ----------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---- ---- ------------ ------------- ---------
 APOPT (v1.0)           2         1        30        26   26    0  0.00000E+00         0.065 Success
 BPOPT (v1.0)           2         1         0        18   17    0  0.00000E+00         0.004 Success
 IPOPT (v3.12)          2         1        22        17   15    0  0.00000E+00         0.019 Success
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```